# Hasura Auth Clarifications

Tags: hasura, hasura-jwt

I have 2 things which i would like to confirm before moving forward with the workaround i have in mind.

1. When using JWT Auth with HS256 algorithm, i have a key which is less than 32 characters in length. I'm getting this error - "Error in $: Invalid JWK: Key size too small; should be at least 32 characters". So is this is an hard requirement ? or is there any trick to change this into a warning instead of an error ?
2. Is it possible for us to customise the Hasura Console Authentication from admin secret ? for lets say to SSO or anything ?

Comment: For the second part of your question, SSO is part of the Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, yes it is a hard requirement. you can read more about it in [RFC 7518](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-3.2)

> A key of the same size as the hash output (for instance, 256 bits for
> "HS256") or larger MUST be used with this algorithm.  (This
> requirement is based on Section 5.3.4 (Security Effect of the HMAC
> Key) of NIST SP 800-117 [NIST.800-107], which states that the
> effective security strength is the minimum of the security strength of
> the key and two times the size of the internal hash value.)